# IE 10 feature sniffing

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10

Im looking for a quick way to feature sniff in javascript to see if the browser is ie10, does anybody know what to look for?

code of what not working:

var w = $(this).width() - 2; 
var top = $(this).next(); 
var mid = $(top).next();
var bot = $(mid).next();

it just crashes the whole of ie and forces me to restart.

Comment: You want to do Browser sniffing not feature sniffing!

Comment: if you feature-sniff you should not care what browser it is...

Comment: Why do you need to know if the browser is ie10?

Comment: ie10 has gotten rid of browser sniffing hasn't it?. but need to know if it ie10 or not, because code works fine in everything else other than ie10. (even past ie's)

Comment: And what is the code that doesn't work in ie10?

Answer (score 1):

[internet explorer 10 user agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[browser detect in js](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)